# Proper way to get current User ID in Entity Framework Core

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, entity-framework-core

There are a bunch of different answers floating around here for the different RC's of ASP.NET Core on how to get the ID of the currently logged in user. I wanted to ask the definite question here. Please note that project.json now has "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore": "1.0.0"

With RC1, you could do something like this:

```
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity;
using System.Security.Claims;

User.GetUserId();
```

But with the newly released version 1 of EF Core, Microsoft.AspNet.Identity is not the right version.

There was suggestions to use UserManager, which seems like a lot just to get the currently logged in user:

```
private Task<ApplicationUser> GetCurrentUserAsync() => _userManager.GetUserAsync(HttpContext.User);

var user = await GetCurrentUserAsync();
var userId = user?.Id;
```

Another method that I found was:

```
private readonly UserManager<ApplicationUser> _userManager;
_userManager.GetUserId(User)
```

So with ASP.NET Core 1 RTM and EF Core 1 with the following libraries in project.json, what is the proper way to get the id of the currently logged in user?

```
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore": "1.0.0",
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc": "1.0.0",
```

Comment: Please don't put tags into question title! http://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging

Answer (score 16, accepted):

ASP.NET Core Identity is injected via DI in the startup.cs - as such you just have to inject UserManager via a constructor

```
UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager
```

You can then use the following in methods

```
_userManager.GetUserId(User);
```

That's the way its used in the Sample Web Application when you create a new ASP.NET Core 1 project with Individual User Account.

Answer (score 29):

If you are accessing this from withing the Controller, then using *UserManager* to get the user ID is pretty inefficient as you are making a round trip to the database. If you are using *ClaimsIdentity*, you can do something like this to get the user id:

```
var claimsIdentity = (ClaimsIdentity)this.User.Identity;
var claim = claimsIdentity.FindFirst(System.Security.Claims.ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier);
var userId = claim.Value;
```

This method just reads the user ID which is already present in the cookie, which in turn is automatically deserialized and stored in a *ClaimsIdentity* instance.

I use this helper class:

```
public static class UserHelpers
{
    public static string GetUserId(this IPrincipal principal)
    {
        var claimsIdentity = (ClaimsIdentity)principal.Identity;
        var claim = claimsIdentity.FindFirst(System.Security.Claims.ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier);
        return claim.Value;
    }
}
```

So getting a user ID becomes:

```
var userId = this.User.GetUserId();
```

If, for some reason, the required claim is not present in the *Claims* colleciton, you can easily add it when creating the user's *ClaimsIdentity*:

```
public class ApplicaionUser : IdentityUser
{
    public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<User> manager)
    {
        var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
        userIdentity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, this.UserId));
        return userIdentity;
    }
}
```

Comment: im surprised there is no built-in way to get a currently logged in UserID. Is this method any different to how the old Users.Identity.GetUserId() works or behaves?

Comment: This method uses the same basic logic as the old GetUserId. The difference is that you can call it directly on the User object instead of User.Idenity object. Check this answer for a comparison http://stackoverflow.com/a/28520274/1396972. I believe the reason why they removed it is because of the cast to ClaimsIdentity which is a violation of  LSP.

Comment: Used this for an asp.net core application on framework 4.5.2. Adding the nuget package Microsoft.AspNet.Identity caused ambiguity and conflicts with existing framework references.

Comment: And in 2020 (ASP.NET Core 3.1) people are still trying to figure out the same thing! And it looks like this is still the same best answer. Why they don't add an 'Id' property to `User.Identity` is a complete mystery.

Answer (score 2):

The one-liner below is a more concise version of the other answers above.

```
var user = User.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).Value;
```

To explain a little further, I wanted to use the most basic form of authentication without any tables in the database so I chose this one - 
[Using Cookie Authentication without ASP.NET Core Identity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/cookie?tabs=aspnetcore2x) from the Core documentation.

To get this working, the first step is to add the services in Startup.cs

```
services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddCookie(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, options =>
        {
        options.LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login/");
        options.LogoutPath = new PathString("/Account/Logoff/");
        options.AccessDeniedPath = new PathString("/Account/AccessDenied/");
        options.Cookie.SecurePolicy = CookieSecurePolicy.SameAsRequest;
        });

services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(identityOptionsCookies =>
{
    // See https://andrewlock.net/automatically-validating-anti-forgery-tokens-in-asp-net-core-with-the-autovalidateantiforgerytokenattribute/
    identityOptionsCookies.Cookie.SecurePolicy = CookieSecurePolicy.SameAsRequest;
});
```

Then in the AccountController on the post back having entered a valid user id and password, the simplest Claims based authentication is to just add the login id as a Claim, e.g.

var claims = new List
                {
                    new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, loginViewModel.Guid, ClaimValueTypes.String, issuer),
                };

```
            var claimsIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);

            var principal = new ClaimsPrincipal(claimsIdentity);

            await HttpContext.SignInAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, principal,
                new AuthenticationProperties
                {
                    ExpiresUtc = DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(_cookieTimeoutInMinutes),
                    IsPersistent = true,
                    AllowRefresh = false
                });
```

Once the Sign In completes you can retrieve the user id as described in the one liner above. See the answer from Milos Mrdovic above for the more detailed steps.

```
var user = User.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).Value;
```

See [Claims-Based Authorization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/claims) for further information.

Comment: Done @PetterFriberg :).

Answer (score 0):

You can get UserId by this way also.

```
public class Program
   {
           private readonly SignInManager<ApplicationUser> _signInManager;

           public Program(SignInManager<ApplicationUser> signInManager)
           {
               _signInManager = signInManager;
              var UserId = _signInManager.Context.User.Claims.FirstOrDefault().Value;
           }
   }
```

Where ApplicationUser class is given below....

```
public class ApplicationUser:IdentityUser
    {
        [Column(TypeName = "Nvarchar(500)")]
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        [Column(TypeName = "Nvarchar(500)")]
        public string MiddleName { get; set; }
        [Column(TypeName = "Nvarchar(500)")]
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        [Column(TypeName = "DateTime")]
        public DateTime? LastAccess { get; set; }
    }
```

And Your ApplicationUser class should inherited by IdentityUser.