# How to get user's id inside an Entity Framework DbContext

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core

I need to track database changes in net core 2.0 EF. It all works but I don't know how to get userId  inside DbContext. I need to get UserId to assign changes to the user. I cannot simply run `_userManager.GetUserId(HttpContext.User).ToString();`. Any suggestions? Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Proper way to get current User ID in Entity Framework Core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38543193/proper-way-to-get-current-user-id-in-entity-framework-core)

Comment: Don't let any DbContext class find user Ids from any application context, it violates the single responsibility principle. You *may* enter a user Id  by a constructor parameter.

Answer (score 5):

In your `ConfigureServices` method in `Startup.cs` add:

```
services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();
services.AddEntityFrameworkSqlServer();
```

The `services.AddEntityFrameworkSqlServer()` bit adds the service resolver into your context, allowing you to utilize the`GetService` extension method on your context.

Then, inside your context you can do:

```
var httpContextAccessor = this.GetService<IHttpContextAccessor>();
```

The result may be null, particularly if the context is not running within a web application (i.e. during migrations, console apps utilizing your context, etc.). As a result, you should do proper null checking. The following uses C# 6's null-conditional operator:

```
var userId = httpContextAccessor?.HttpContext.User.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier);
```

Then, `userId` will either have the id of the currently logged in user or be null.

Comment: Actually I override async Task<int> SaveChangesAsync method and from inside I don't have access to contex. Could you explain my a little more?

Comment: Sorry. That should be `this` instead of `context`.

Comment: I tried pointer this. earlier.  But the method GetService is not available. Maybe there is some special configuration to use DI within dbcontex. Should DI work in dbcontext? Sorry for so many questions.

Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error CS1061 'ApplicationDbContext' does not contain a definition for 'GetService' and no extension method 'GetService' accepting a first argument of type 'ApplicationDbContext' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: @Lukas have you tried adding: using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure;

Comment: I am trying to do the same with EF Core 2.0 and no matter what I do the `Identity.Name` is null and `Identity.Claims` is an empty list...  When I try to inject `UserManager<ApplicationUser>` into my context I get a circular dependency error.  Any suggestions?

Comment: This only works within the context of a request. If you attempt to use this outside the request pipeline, the user will always be null. Otherwise, it should work fine. You cannot inject UserManager into your context because UserManager depends on your context. It's essentially a wrapper around it.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  Does that mean there's no way to do this inside the context, and I will need to set the field elsewhere for every object before saving?

Comment: No. You can do this inside the context, but your context must be instantiate by the service collection as part of servicing a particular request. You can't do it in something like a console app or during migration, etc.

Comment: This solution returns null

Comment: Then you're not using it within the request pipeline, which is the only place it will work. In other words, there must actually be an HttpContext in the first place.